# textchanged event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, textbox

I have CalendarExtender and bound it to a textbox but when i write code in textchanged event found that it doesn't fire;here my code snippet:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" MaxLength="10" Width="150" CssClass="textbox" 
    runat="server" />
```

code behind :

```
protected void txtFromDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text) < DateTime.Today)
    {
        _lblErroFromDate.Visible = true;
        _lblErroFromDate.Text = "Please enter valid date !";
    }
    else
        _lblErroFromDate.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TextChanged` event wont be fired until the page posts back to the server.

`TextBox` controls don't post back the page to the server by default when their events occure. You can change this behavior by setting the `AutoPostBack` property value to *true*.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to set `AutoPostBack="true"`.

Answer (score 2):

I think setting `AutoPostBack` property to `true` will solve the problem.